# Dynamic Attachment Size for Paperclip (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

Is there anyway to have the validates_attachment_size except a dynamic file size limit? Here's an example:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :folder
   has_attached_file :document
   validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => get_current_file_size_limit

   private

   def get_current_file_size_limit
     10.megabytes # This will dynamically change
   end
end
```

I've tried this but I keep getting an error saying "unknown method". Lambdas and Procs don't work either. Has anyone ever tried this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paperclip doesn't allow to pass function as size limit parameter. So you probably need to write custom validation:

```
  validate :validate_image_size

  def validate_image_size
    if document.file? && document.size > get_current_file_size_limit
      errors.add_to_base(" ... Your error message")
    end
  end
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! I was hoping there would be a little bit nicer way but I guess not for now. Maybe I'll submit a patch to Paperclip. :)

Answer (score 2):

Long shot...

`validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => :get_current_file_size_limit`

Usually when passing a function you have to pass the symbol and not the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in Paperclip validation now:

```
validates_attachment_size :mp3, :less_than => 10.megabytes
```

Change mp3 to whatever your paperclipped file's name is.

See this post for more helpful Paperclip tips: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip